# Winget sql logic error 0x87af0001 sql error or missing database when trying to update or list packages

Tags: windows, winget, oh-my-posh

So, I have to update the windows package `oh-my-posh`, and I try to use the indicated command `winget upgrade oh-my-posh`. But the result is this:

```
sql logic error
0x87af0001 : sql error or missing database
```

I also get this when I try to list All the Packages installed.
Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was posted by user sercannaya on the official `winget-cli` github repo, issue [#1999](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1999#issuecomment-1127497598):

> I was having the same problem recently. I deleted the "installed.db"
> file and solved the problem.
>
> The location of the file "installed.db":
>
> `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\StoreEdgeFD`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried updating your sources?
`winget source update --force` in admin mode.

Are you using the latest client?
As of July 2022 the latest [1.3.1741 release candidate](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.1741) is out at GitHub.